# access variable in backing bean from jsf page

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

I have two primefaces panel components in jsf page.I want to show some data on panels via clicking primefaces commandButton and show panel1 when page load.When clicking commandbutton,I do not want to show other panel.So  I defined boolean variables in backing bean to use in visible property of panels.But it does not work.

Backing Bean:

```
 @ManagedBean
 @SessionScoped
 public class Bean implements Serializable {
   private boolean show;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init(){
      this.show=true;
   }
   public void action_commandButton(){
      this.show=false;
   }
  }
```

Jsf Page

```
  <p:commandButton style="text-align: center;font-size:12px;"  
                             action="#{bean.action_commandButton()}"  value=""/>

 <!--panel 1 -->
  <p:panel visible="#{bean.show}">
      <p:dataGrid>
        <!-- data from datbase-->
      </p:dataGrid>
  </p:panel>

  <!-- panel 2-->
  <p:panel visible="#{!bean.show}">
      <p:dataGrid>
        <!-- data from datbase-->
      </p:dataGrid>
  </p:panel>
```

How to solve this problem?
  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the JSF markup for the command button?  Is this an Ajax request or a full page post back?

Comment: Why aren't you using `rendered` attribute in order of `visible`?

Comment: I'm confused on the problem I have datagrid components in panels.So I try to panel visible property.

Comment: Tip: it would be better to change the scope of your bean to `@ViewScoped` so the bean would be created per page access and not once by session.

Comment: I think you just need to add a get and set method for "show". the private field cannot be accessed without.

Comment: I have already have getter and setters for "show"

Comment: If `p:commandButton` is updating nothing, it won't work. So if you have already achieved the correct way publish it and mark your own answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks everyone try to help I set p:commandButton update="@form"  and worked